# How to make a ViewModel in knockout.js bind to an anonymous collection returned from a WebAPI?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, viewmodel

below code works for me

```
<div id="TickerBox" style="float: right;">
    Newly Added Customer  :<span data-bind="text: lastCustomer"></span><br />
    Newly Added Product   :<span data-bind="text: lastProduct"></span><br />
    Newly Added Company   :<span data-bind="text: lastCompany"></span><br />
    Total No of Customers :<span data-bind="text: customerCount"></span><br />
    Total No of Products  :<span data-bind="text: productCount"></span><br />
    Total No of Companies :<span data-bind="text: companyCount"></span><br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myViewModel =
        {
            lastCustomer: ko.observable(''),
            lastProduct: ko.observable(''),
            lastCompany: ko.observable(''),
            productCount: ko.observable(0),
            customerCount: ko.observable(0),
            companyCount: ko.observable(0)
        }

    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('TickerBox'));

    $.getJSON('/api/product', function (data) {
        myViewModel.companyCount(data.companyCount);
        myViewModel.customerCount(data.customerCount);
        myViewModel.productCount(data.productCount);
        myViewModel.lastCompany(data.lastCompany);
        myViewModel.lastCustomer(data.lastCustomer);
        myViewModel.lastProduct(data.lastProduct);
    });
</script>
```

But I wanted to make a ViewModel such that , it could directly bind with the JSON object when calling AJAX Request. Instead of each time assiging each observable the value , can the ViewModel be optimized as a collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)?

You use it like this:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
```

inside your getJSON success function.

Comment: Thanks ... this JS didnt come with NuGetPackages ... nevertheless i wasn't aware about this mapping... let me try and check if this would work

Comment: As your observable fields have the same names as your JSON data, it should just work automatically. If it doesn't you can customise the mapping to make it work.